# Change layout of Facebook authentication button in asp.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, layout, facebook-login

As a semester project, friends and I are working on a Planning application in ASP.NET Core MVC. We have enabled Facebook login, but the button is rather simple and I would like to be able to change the layout of the register-with-facebook button.

We recently changed from ASP.NET Framework to Core, and in Framework I could change it in a file called _ExternalLoginListPartial.cshtml. I have looked around in all folders, but can't find the same or any other file related to have the same content of that file.

The way I did it in Framework were like so

```
@foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
{
    switch (@p.AuthenticationType)
    {
        case "Facebook":
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default facebookButton" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
            break;
           .
           .
         ..and so for other types..
    }
}
```

**Edit**

@Chris Pratt gave a good solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377364/change-layout-of-facebook-authentication-button-in-asp-net-core-mvc/55377600#55377600)

In the Login.cshtml from the Scaffolded items list, I made these changes:

```
@foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
    {
    switch (@provider.DisplayName)
        {
            case "Facebook":
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default facebookButton" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                  break;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity now comes with a Default UI. It's a Razor Class Library composed of Razor Pages and embedded static files, that's included via calling `AddDefaultIdentity` (which internally calls `AddDefaultUI`). As such, nothing physically exists in your project, even though everything functions as if it was directly in your project.

If you want to customize this UI, you can either turn it off (by use `AddIdentity` instead) and build whatever you like, or (more likely) you'll want to simply scaffold in the Razor Page(s) you want to customize. Anything actually in your project will effectively override anything coming from the Default UI.

Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and choose Add > New Scaffolded Item. There's a tab there for Identity, with one scaffold. When you choose this, you'll be presented with a list of the various Razor Pages that can be scaffolded in. Select one or more you'd like to customize (or just include everything, if you like).

For this particular change, you'll find the code in `Login.cshtml`.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I have added the Login.cshtml and a couple of other files from the Scaffolded items list, and edited the Facebook login button, to look as I wanted to.

Comment: i have my own login.html page in .netcore project is it possible to show facebook login botton instead of default signup page and gets response in any controller i want ?